# Complex message not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer, messages, di

I've followed this tutorial: https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/displaying-complex-error-messages-in-magento-2.html

This is my di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\MessageConfigurationsPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configurationsMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="PortailAxiane" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="renderer" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\Renderer\BlockRenderer::CODE</item>
                    <item name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Portail_Axiane::custommessage.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This is my custommessage.phtml

```
<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getData('url'))?>
```

And my message in my observer :

```
$this->_messageManager->addComplexErrorMessage(
                        'PortailAxiane',
                        array(
                            "url" => $produtToAddUrl
                        ), null
                    );
```

But as the result, I only have the red rectangle. What did I missed ?

Comment: I think you should check var/log exception.log and system.log files

Comment: No exceptions inside

Answer (score 2):

It appears code relating to messaging needs to go in the view you wish to add it to. So ensure your `di.xml` file is located at:

`etc/frontend/di.xml`
or
`etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

instead of just
`etc/di.xml`

Comment: anybody have complete module the above **complex message**

Comment: yes, I actually built one around the time of this post https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-messages

Answer (score 1):

Mark Shust's answer worked for me.
So you need to create another one `di.xml` in `etc/frontend` or `etc/adminhtml` (depending on what area you need) folder of your module.
And then add this code to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\MessageConfigurationsPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configurationsMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="identifierName" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="renderer" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\Renderer\BlockRenderer::CODE</item>
                    <item name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::messages/example-message.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```